# $(document).ready(function() fires too early

Tags: jquery

I checked in Chrome console that `(document).ready` fires when the relevant HTML elements are not present in DOM yet. Any idea why it happens? The code goes to `QtyChng` function and only highlights the selector line. This should be fine as it applies the event listener, but as it happens too early, this listener won't work.

```js
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function(){   
        QtyChng();
    });

    function QtyChng() {
        $(".woocommerce form.cart, .woocommerce td.product-quantity, .woocommerce li.product").off("click", ".qib-button").on( "click", ".qib-button", function() {
            // do stuff     
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are those elements part of the initial HTML source or are they loaded dynamically?

Comment: `$(document).ready()` fires when the DOM loads, not magically when you add things later.

Comment: I see the problem now - some plugin puts JavaScript inline and it includes HTML elements that I expected, it must be recreating them later.

Comment: You can probably use event delegation to capture the _click_ event. Not sure if you'll have much luck using `.off()` though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Thanks, Phil. Replacing `$(".woocommerce form.cart, .woocommerce td.product-quantity, .woocommerce li.product")` with `$(document)` solved the issue for 2 plugin users with similar problem. I read that it won't have a significant performance impact as some people would claim, so I'm going to stick with this solution for compatibility sake.